# ajax forms won't submit properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Perhaps I am just severely confused. I am relatively new to AJAX. I have multiple forms on a single page that I am ultimately trying to submit, but for the moment, I just want to submit the specific form whose submit button was clicked. I've brought my "options" and "binding" into my single function because of scope issues, but I'm also happy to work outside of it. This doesn't work (an attempt to select the form based on a form class it shares with other forms on the page, but singling out its particular id):

```
$('.teacher_account_form').submit(function(){
var form_submitted = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(form_submitted);

var options = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/users/p_teacher_account_work",
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $('#pay_output').html("Updating...");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#pay_output').html(response);
    }
};

// Using the above options, ajax'ify the form
$(form_submitted).ajaxForm(options);    

});
```

the below works, but it means I am hardcoding my form id for binding:

```
var options = {
type: 'POST',
url: "/users/p_teacher_account_work",
beforeSubmit: function() {
    $('#pay_output').html("Updating...");
},
success: function(response) {
    $('#pay_output').html(response);
}
};

// Using the above options, ajax'ify the form
$('#pay_form').ajaxForm(options);
```

And by works, I mean I get my success message echo'd back to the page from the php file, and the database updates.

UPDATE: I am using a button, not an input type = "submit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create empty js objects. Solution below:

```
var which_button;
$('.account_submit').click(function() {
    which_button = $(this).attr('id');

    // Create empty jQuery objects -
    var $jsOutput = $([]);
    var $jsForm = $([]);

    // url to submit to
    var ajaxURL = "/users/p_teacher_account_work";

    // Assign jQuery selector objects
    switch (which_button) {
        case "work_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#pay_output');
            $jsForm = $('#pay_form');
            break;
        case "edu_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#edu_output');
            $jsForm = $('#edu_form');
            break;
        case "image_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#image_output');
            $jsForm = $('#image_form');
            break;
        case "personal_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#personal_output');
            $jsForm = $('#personal_form');
            break;
    }

    // Lock and load the ajax request -
    var ajax_options = {
        type: 'post',
        url: ajaxURL,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Display a loading message while waiting for the ajax call to complete
            $jsOutput.html("Updating...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $jsOutput.html(response);
        }
    };
    $jsForm.ajaxForm( ajax_options );


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.teacher_account_form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
/* var form_submitted = $(this).attr('id'); omit this line */
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/users/p_teacher_account_work",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $('#pay_output').html("Updating...");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#pay_output').html(response);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: We all make mistakes @KevinBowersox

Comment: seems like it might have worked once, then getting this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Comment: the word settings is not included in my code you must have left some of your original code in by mistake

Comment: wondering what this line: var form_submitted = $(this).attr('id');
still does?

Comment: i think that line can be safely omitted

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is not used `onsubmit`, unless you `eventObject.preventDefault()` or `return false;`. If you change your submit to a button and make that `click` instead of `submit`, then you page will work, if there are no other errors.

Comment: I actually am using a button:                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-med" id="sub_button" name="sub_button">Update Work</button>

Comment: Obviously, I mean `<input type='button' />`, or `<button type='button'></button>`, instead of any `type='submit'`.

Answer (score 0):

If your performing an `ajax` call on submit of the form you need to prevent the actual form from submitting:

```
$('.teacher_account_form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had somewhat similar problem and what i did was this:

```
 1. form action="##"
 2. instead of input type="submit", use type="button"
 3. at input type="button" add onclick attribute to your function instead of using $("#id").blah
 // Call your function like this
 // example: <input type="button" onclick="some_function()" />
 4. Test your code.
```

this is what i am currently doing and i am having no problems.
this prevents form from being submitted other than by the function assigned to it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: any chance you want to be more specific, code-wise? not sure what you mean in step 3

Comment: I added an example to demonstrate after number 3. i use this to make it clearer for my coding and it creates less problems.